# Load a custom server control from another custom server control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two custom server controls in a ASP.NET page,
one builds a chart, the other one plays the builded chart.

so my problem is to load the player when the chart is built.

so i send the file to the builder and now ii want just to load it

```
gChartPlayer Player = new gChartPlayer();
Player.XML_FILE = ChartFile;
```

something like `Player.Load()`,

can someone help me??

Answer (score 0):

Question isn't really clear but if you want to decide when to load a usercontrol you can use `LoadControl` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: gChartPlayer is a custom server control (gChartPlayer.cs).

Comment: you can load any usercontrol if you know its type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `Add Method`

Code : `this.Controls.Add`

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277578(v=vs.60).aspx